# Angularjs: load contents from local json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is my code, I am trying to display the JSON contents, when I checked in console, the `data` which was getting returned was the whole html code, instead of json data. Where am i going wrong?

```html
<html ng-app="BooksApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var BooksApp = angular.module('BooksApp', []);
        BooksApp.controller("BookCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('books.json').success(function (data) {
                $scope.books = data;
                console.log(data);
            });
    }]);
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="BookCtrl">
    <h2>Angular.js </h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Book Price</th>
        </tr>
        <option ng-repeat="entry in books.books" value="{{entry.name}}">{{entry.name}}</option>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

books.json

```json
{
    "books": [{
        "id": 2081,
        "name": "python",
        "price": "1000"
    }, {
        "id": 8029,
        "name": "c++",
        "price": "2000"
    }],
    "count": 2
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

app.js

```JS
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');


fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean *"it is the whole html code"*? Show sample of exactly what you see

Comment: @charlietfl The first code on top which I have pasted !!

Comment: @charlietfl: It works perfectly fine when I directly assign $scope.books to JSON

Comment: that doesn't explain what is currently being returned and what you mean by *"html"*

Comment: @charlietfl I added a screenshot

Comment: seems like you have a server side routing problem if you are requesting a json file and it is returning an html file

Comment: Are your `index.html` and `books.json` present in same file. and can you show the whoe console log? I want to see what it prints from the start

Comment: @ravishankar OP is already showing what prints in console...it is index.html

Comment: You need more advanced routing than what is shown. Might try using a framework like express

Comment: @ravishankar Yeah, they are in same directory, it is printing index.html

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, I will try it

Comment: i just wanted to see the start of it, sometimes in case of error, it prints the whole html file.

Comment: @ravishankar I'm sorry, that's the start  :(

Comment: did you try with leading slash `/` as `/books.json` in the url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AngularJS using to create SPA app, you need to run it separate from the backend. But it seem that you use node to serve the static file also want to get book.json from it.

The new approach:

The server side, just create an api that return `book.json` via api `/books`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
fs = require('fs');

app.get('/books', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('books.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(data);
        res.send(data)
    });

})

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

The client side, call to that server

```
$http.get('http://localhost/books').success(function(data) {
   $scope.books = data;
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: But now it's not rendering index.html..just showing the JSON text

Comment: You can serve the HTML static file by another web sever, nginx for example, or just simple `Web Server for Chrome`. This approach is separate the server side and client side.
If you want to read json file from client side, just get it like this ```$http.get('books.json').then(function(response) {
            console.log('books.json', response);
        });```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that this can happen when Angular isn't able to find the file specified in a `$http.get()` request. Also, the `.success` return from an angular $http.get() function has been deprecated. Instead, use the `$http.get(...)`**.then** way of doing this as stated in the angular documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

You also may want to use an errorCallback as stated in the docs and output error information to the console - this may give you more information about what's happening.

Also, I don't know why you'd want to use the filesystem to read the ./index.html file rather than use a local (and free) webserver such as Apache. I doubt you'll have full access to the filesystem if you end up hosting your site on a hosted server.

https://httpd.apache.org/

Lastly, if you're just learning AngularJS, you may want to start with a sample project to see how Angular projects are structured such as the following official small seed project.

https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Hope that helps.